# Configure Spring Boot to use Custom Access Token converter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to get user information from the access token provided by an Identity Provider. The Identity Provider that I'm using provides it's scope in the form of a string instead of a list because of which the DefaultAccessTokenConverter doesn't work for me. As a result I wish to extend it to a CustomAccessTokenConverter to override it's extractAuthentication() method. I'm using the following in my security config to make Spring use this custom class instead of the default one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomAccessTokenConverter customAccessTokenConverter;

    // For validating the incoming access token and fetching user information from it
    @Bean
    public ResourceServerTokenServices createResourceServerTokenServices() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(*Introspection URL*);
        tokenServices.setClientId(*Client ID*);
        tokenServices.setClientSecret(*Client Secret*);
        return tokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return customAccessTokenConverter;
    }
}
```

**But, Spring still uses the DefaultAccessTokenConverter. What am I doing wrong? Please help me out here.**

Here is what my CustomAccessTokenConverter class looks like just for reference:

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessTokenConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter {

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
        .
        .
        .
        return new OAuth2Authentication(request, user);
    }
}
```

I am using Spring Boot with the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I figured it out while I was drafting the question, I had been thinking about if for an hour and then I gave up and started drafting this question although while adding the code for the resource token services I figured that there might be something here to add a access token converter and luckily it did have. I didn't want to just chuck the draft as I had been working on it for 10 mins, so I just went ahead and posted the question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

ResourceTokenServices allows us to use our own AccessTokenConverter.

Simply add the following to your security config:

```
@Bean
public ResourceServerTokenServices createResourceServerTokenServices() {
    RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(*Introspection URL*);
    tokenServices.setClientId(*Client ID*);
    tokenServices.setClientSecret(*Client Secret*);
    // ADD THE NEXT LINE
    tokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(customAccessTokenConverter);
    return tokenServices;
}
```